# Возможно ли с помощью Beautiful Soup, спарсить style

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Проблема такая, нужно спрасить `<div id="model-fun" style="background-image: url(https://www.fanfdun.ru/images/model/aa9d45f5/320/main.jpg);"`
И получить только ссылку данного тега `style`, как это сделать ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

с помощью метода `get` обьекта соупа берем `style`, а дальше регуляркой берем ссылку из `style`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


html = r'''
    <div id="model-fun" style="background-image: url(https://www.fanfdun.ru/images/model/aa9d45f5/320/main.jpg);"</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('div')
style = div.get('style')
print(style)

links = re.findall(r'url\((.+)\)', style)
print(links[0])
```

**вывод:**

```
background-image: url(https://www.fanfdun.ru/images/model/aa9d45f5/320/main.jpg);
https://www.fanfdun.ru/images/model/aa9d45f5/320/main.jpg
```